# Basic calculations "Multiple markers on this line syntax error, delete this token"

Tags: java

Hello I am just beginning to learn java and am having trouble with some very basic calculations. This simple program asks the user to input two values and then when it runs I want it to show "20 + 5 = 25". However I am repeatedly receiving the "syntax error, delete this token" message on this portion of the line `"+" num2 "=" num1`. What is wrong?

```
package ner.cs1451;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project01a {
/*This program asks the user to input two values
 *Then computes the following: sum, difference, product, quotient, remainder, and the average.*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int num1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
        int num2 = in.nextInt();
        int avg = (num1 + num2)/2;


        System.out.println(num1 "+" num2 "=" num1 + num2);
        System.out.println(num1 "-" num2 "=" num1 - num2);
        System.out.println(num1 "*" num2 "=" num1 * num2);
        System.out.println(num1 "/" num2 "=" num1 / num2);
        System.out.println(num1 "%" num2 "=" num1 % num2);
        System.out.println("The average of your two numbers is: "+avg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the strings like this:

`System.out.println(num1 +  "+" + num2 + "=" + (num1 + num2));`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the concatenation operator `+` between all values you're attempting to concatenate.  E.g.

```
System.out.println(num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + (num1 + num2));
```

You'll also want to surround the addition with parentheses, so that normal addition takes place between the numbers, instead of concatenation.